# MongoDB record missing after insertion

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am using MongoDB 2.4.5 64 bit on Linux using C++ API to insert 1 M record

I did turn on write concern after the connection

```
   mongo.setWriteConcern(mongo::W_NORMAL);

   for (int i=0; i<RECORDS; i++) {
        mongo::BSONObj record = BSON (
                "_id" << i <<
                "mystring" << "hello world" );
        bulk_data.push_back(record);

        if (i % 10000 == 0) {
            mongo.insert("insert_test.col1", bulk_data);

        }
    }
```

Surprisingly at the end when I do count (via count(), it only shows 990001  records from collection 'insert_test.col1'.

What did I do wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can see you got this example code from [here](http://tebros.com/2010/11/mongodb-bulk-inserts-with-the-c-driver/), but they have the same bug... I've left a comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `mongo.insert("insert_test.col1", bulk_data);` at the end of (immediately after) your loop -- unless `RECORDS` is one less than a multiple of 10000 (you said it was 1000000, which isn't), then the last 9999 iterations are not inserted because they're still in `bulk_data`!

In other words, `i` is only `999999` on the last iteration through the loop, so the `if` isn't entered, and the last 9999 records that were put in `bulk_data` are not inserted.

Also, `bulk_data` needs to be cleared after being inserted:

```
if (i % 10000 == 0) {
    mongo.insert("insert_test.col1", bulk_data);
    bulk_data.clear();  //  <-----
}
```